# Como ordenar o array "timeline" por ordem de data decrescente no PHP?

Tags: php

Como ordenar o array "timeline" por ordem de data decrescente no PHP ?

```
"bookingAnalysis": {
    "timeline": [
      {
        "date": "2017-12-02",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-12-01",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 4
      },
      {
        "date": "2017-12-08",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 4
      },     
      {
        "date": "2017-12-29",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-01-12",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-01-19",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-01-21",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-01-27",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 2
      },
      {
        "date": "2018-01-10",
        "count": 1,
        "peopleCount": 6
      },      
    ],
  }
```

Comment: o dado para ser ordenado vem assim no formato `json`?

Comment: Sim, estou recebendo um json e preciso ordena-lo.

Comment: Precisar colocar o Jason completo apesar que a resposta não muda muito

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A resposta é simples, nada de complicada já visto que o layout da sua data sugere a utilização da função [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php) da seguinte forma, um ***exemplo básico***:

```
<?php

var_dump(strtotime("1999-01-01") > strtotime("1999-01-02")); // false
var_dump(strtotime("1999-01-02") > strtotime("1999-01-01")); // true
```

Como isso deve ser um `array` de informações vou gerar um exemplo minimo, com a função [usort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php) com [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php):

```
<?php

$data = array(
    array("date" => "2018-01-21", "count" => 1, "peopleCount"=> 2),
    array("date" => "2018-01-22", "count" => 1, "peopleCount"=> 3),
    array("date" => "2018-01-19", "count" => 1, "peopleCount"=> 4),
    array("date" => "2018-01-25", "count" => 1, "peopleCount"=> 5)
    );


usort($data, function($d1, $d2){
    $t1 = strtotime($d1['date']);
    $t2 = strtotime($d2['date']);
    if ($t1 === $t2) return 0;
    return ($t1 > $t2) ? -1 : 1;
});

var_dump($data);
```

[Verifique o exemplo Online](https://ideone.com/HBvToX)

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php)
- [usort](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.usort.php)